# How can I save what I'm writing in a TextField to CoreData?

Tags: swift, swiftui

i'm trying to save what i'm typing into core data. So, if somone accidentaly closed the app, the text need to remain in the TextField. This is how i'm trying to do it, but i'm getting this error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Cart deliveryAddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002276a00'

This is my View :

```
struct LivrareView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    var carts: FetchedResults<Cart>
    @State var adresaTextField : String = ""
    @State var telefonTextField : String = ""
    @State var tacamuriSwitch: Bool = false
    @State var oraLivrare: String = ""
    @State var specificatiiTextEditor: String = "Ex : Nu merge interfonu"
    @ObservedObject var cart : Cart 
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(Texts.livrareViewText1)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
            TextField("Ex: str. 16 Decembrie 1989, nr, 23, ap 1, et 1", text: $cart.wrappedDeliveryAddress, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                let newCart = Cart(context: viewContext)
                newCart.deliveryAddress = cart.wrappedDeliveryAddress
                print(newCart.deliveryAddress)
                do {
                    try  viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let error = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error\(error)")
                }
                
            })

        }

        }
        .padding(34)
    }
    public init(model: Cart? = nil) {
        self.cart = model ?? Cart()
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my Cart. I'm using codegen : " Manually / none "

```
@objc(Cart)
public class Cart: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {

}
extension Cart {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Cart> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Cart>(entityName: "Cart")
    }

   
    @NSManaged public var grams: Double
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: Int32
    @NSManaged public var deliveryAddress: String?
    public var wrappedDeliveryAddress : String {
        get { deliveryAddress ?? ""}
        set { deliveryAddress = newValue}
    }

}
```

This is a photo of my Core Data Model:

[image: Core Data Model]

How can i make this work ?

This is where i'm calling the View :

```
        TabView(selection: self.$index){
            
            LivrareView()
                .tag(0)
            RidicareView()
                .tag(1)
            
            
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Comment: Do you have a view that calls `LivrareView` and passes in a `Cart`? It seems your issue is in your public init. You are not creating a proper `Cart` if the `Cart` passed to `LivrareView` is nil. It needs to be created like you did in your `.onEditingChanged()` code: `Cart(context: viewContext)`. Also, your declared `Cart` that is being passed in is not being properly assigned as an `ObservedObject`, and I doubt that you even need this, but there isn't enough code to determine it. Lastly, please make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb , yes, i have anorher view that is using this and that s why i m using that public init.

Comment: Can we see it? Also, please cut out the code that is not actually necessary outside of the `TextField` that you want to save in Core Data. It make things easier to explain and fix. If you read the link above, it will show you the process.

Comment: The way you are creating the Cart() in the init is invalid. Don’t allow an optional there. It needs a context to be valid and it isn’t available there.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new cart on editing that doesn’t make sense. It is just going into limbo

Comment: @Yrb i have edited the post now, you can check it now.

Comment: @loremipsum i know the public init () is the issue, how can i make this work ?

Comment: The new item has to come from the parent view. Don’t try to make it in the init. And definitely take it out of on editing. Get rid of that custom init. Make it work with the one that is made by the struct

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460817/core-data-value-check-swiftui) is another method too

Comment: @loremipsum see his updated code. It is simply a `Tabview`. `LivrareView` IS the initial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is trying to create a `Cart` in the public init. Essentially, you are saying if the prior view gives me a `Cart` use it, otherwise, I am going to make my own `Cart` that doesn't exist in the managed object context. Since you never pass a `Cart` in to this view, you only get a `Cart` that is not in context. The first rule of Core Data is you have to operate in the same context. (Rule 2 is sometimes you can violate this, but not as a beginner.) When you try to use it, you get the error. And, the way you have things set up, you don't need it.

I condensed `LivrareView` down to the bare minimum, and then added some `Text()` views so you can see what is going on. First, you already have a `@State` variable for adresa. You don't need the `@ObservedObject var cart` for that. Then, when the time comes, you put the `adresaTextField` in to `newCart.wrappedDeliveryAddress` (you made it, you just as well use it exclusively and make `deliveryAddress` private) and then save your entity. I moved the save out of the `.onEditingChange` into an `.onSubmit()` to save a little sanity, but the bug will become apparent when you use this code. You are creating a new entity every time you hit return (instead of every keystroke as your code had). I think this is what you were trying to avoid when you created the `@ObservedObject var cart`, but that won't work. Your better plan is simply to use all `@State` variables, collect your data and then create and save your managed object with a "save" button. I would also validate your entries first, before you allow a save.

```
struct LivrareView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var carts: FetchedResults<Cart>
    @State var adresaTextField : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TextField("Ex: str. 16 Decembrie 1989, nr, 23, ap 1, et 1", text: $adresaTextField)
                    .onSubmit {
                        let newCart = Cart(context: viewContext)
                        newCart.wrappedDeliveryAddress = adresaTextField
                        print(newCart.wrappedDeliveryAddress)
                        do {
                            try viewContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            let error = error as NSError
                            fatalError("Unresolved error\(error)")
                        }
                    }
                Text("adresaTextField is \(adresaTextField)")
                Text("Managed Objects:")
                ForEach(carts) { cart in
                    Text(cart.wrappedDeliveryAddress)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
Also, a suggestion to save you some heartache when using Core Data with manual codegen. Create a third extension file to put your custom code in. If you change your attributes and need to regenerate the extensions, you will erase your custom code. I call mine "Cart+CoreDataWrappedProperties". You can use what naming extension you want, but it will not be replaced if you regenerate the code. Ask me how I know.